# To remove focuse on editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, autofocus

I need a help that to remove focuses  on edit text in android.

i used this

```
android:focusable="false"
```

but it disables the edit text. Please help me,
and if possible post the code

Comment: add your layout XML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then use this code it works

`android:focusable="true"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Comment: <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/entry_drop"
            android:layout_margin = "5dp"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Note"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

Comment: U smart buddy,
U must use this in ur linear/relative layout where ur edittext locates

Comment: if ur not of this iisue please mark the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Call editText.clearFocus() on your EditText!

Comment: please i need  in  xml

Comment: It's impossible to have an active EditText that doesn't have focus, and I can't figure out why you need this. Maybe if you share the behavior that you need we can help you. When you have to remove focus on your editText?

Answer (score 0):

add this line in activity

```
android:editable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

This way also help you from removing focus from the EditText .
Add this to ur activity in the manifest which you want to remove the EditText

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```